# In Linux can I direct all traffic from a specific ip address or mac address to file

Tags: linux, logging, ip, iptables

In Linux can I direct all traffic from a specific ip address or mac address to file.

I am look of a way to take all traffic from a specific ip address or mac address and put it into a file. Does iptables or some other command line level tool let me do this. I know about wireshark which is a great tool, but I looking for a low level command line method to do some thing similar.

I don't really want to install additional software on our servers but would still like to get information about traffic from suspicious IP or mac address. Even if this is in binary. I will write a program to translate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture all packets to and from a specific IP address output to a file:

```
tcpdump -i <interface> host <ip address> -w <filename>
```

Capture all packets to and from a specific mac address:

```
tcpdump -i <interface> ether host <mac address> -w <filename>
```

However, a mac address would be local to your network.  If you suspect something untoward is going on with a device on your network, a more direct investigation would likely be more successful.  Find it and see what it is doing.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/360227/67952

Comment: Sure - I suggested the best method for finding it in that question

Comment: By the way, the capture files above can be directly opened in wireshark, which is a great tool for interpreting the data found in a capture - also note that wireshark isn't any less low level than tcpdump, so it can be easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just "see" the traffic and save to file, look into the [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) command.